# CrossRef API query.affiliation for a multi word string

Tags: string, api, filter, booleanquery

I'm learning to use the CROSSREF rest API, and want to search for all DOI's with affiliation to a given university. How do I create a multi word search query for AND, not AND/OR?

There are over 100 million DOI's on CrossRef, but only 8217730 have authors affiliation metadata.

`https://api.crossref.org/works?sample=10&filter=has-affiliation:true`

Now if I want to query search for affiliations with "University of Southern Mississippi," I could use mississippi+university+southern, but this return AND/OR the three words.

I want only affiliations with all three words.

`https://api.crossref.org/works?sample=10&query.affiliation=mississippi+university+southern`

This returns all with the word university or southern or mississippi

CrossRef field query instructions are here
https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc#field-queries
and a github comment about the topic is here
https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc/commit/a4d047e0d1556e80aaab0f4b5aae420da2a99ea2 and here https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc/issues/170

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the sample parameter in your URI. The sample parameter gives you random result.

> Being able to select random results is useful for both testing and sampling. You can use the sample parameter to retrieve random results. 
>   [API description for Sample](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc#sample)

So if you want to query just for all results of '' then use the URI without the sample part. Like:

```
https://api.crossref.org/works?query.affiliation=mississippi+university+southern
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - the problem is that the CrossRef API does not support Boolean operators, it uses scores so I don't think you can get do what OP is trying with the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

CrossRef API doesn’t support Boolean operators. The query.affiliation path returns multiple results with scores. You will see the highest score in the resulting json has a key: value out of ‘chosen: true’.

I believe that they have recently transitioned from Solr to Elasticsearch - https://www.crossref.org/blog/behind-the-scenes-improvements-to-the-rest-api/ - which supports Boolean search - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html - but I’m not sure how to use it on CrossRef API endpoints not if you even can.